# Null out bit columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have a temp table that stores bit columns. I want to do a null check for these columns and make them 'Null'.

My code is

```
isnull(a.isrecordable, 'null')
```

which is throwing an error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null' to data type bit

So the process is, from the temp table where I store this column as `bit`, I want to do `isnull` check and pull out as XML format output which will be converted to JSON by a .Net tool. In the JSON, I want the column to show 'null' when there is no value since I don't want to keep the column away from the JSON report.

**UPDATE:**

Updated my little query. CID cannot be bit so replaced the column :)

Any help?!

Comment: You can't have multiple datatypes in a single column.

Comment: Aside from @SeanLange comment, why do you want this anyways? Change it on the front end.

Comment: I badly wanted to do that but requirement doesn't allow to do so

Comment: if a.isrecordable is NULL are you trying to return the string 'null' or the value NULL ?

Comment: I want to return null and not NULL

Comment: So you can't just store the text `'null'` in a field that is defined as a bit.  But you can format the data as you pull it with your query to show that with `ISNULL()`.  I would personally let the database store the bit values and do any sort of formatting at the presentation layer.  Then you aren't shipping around strings when you could be using booleans.

Comment: Then the field in your temp table cannot be of type bit, 'null' is a string.  If you were going to put the value NULL in there, it would have to be a Nullable bit field.

Comment: Ok also the reason that I'm doing this conversion is I want to see this field hold 'null' in my JSON report when it doesn't have any value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `cast` your bit column to a `varchar` since `isnull` has to compare the same data types:

```
 isnull(cast(cid as varchar(10)), 'null')
```

- [Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/HUHOU35424)

Comment: Thanks @sgeddes this is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The Data type of column (`isrecordable`) for table must match with `'null'`'s data type. i.e. must be of type `varchar`.